# Problem with new upgraded version(0.60) of react native when we linking any third party module

Tags: react-native

In my cases when i link  third  party module  in react native like..

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons --save.


react-native link
```

It gives message for me....
  **React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:-
 react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")**

but if i am not link the module it will not work for me

**this problem  occurs only in react-native new upgraded version(0.60) not for older version**.

please suggest me any solution for the given problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always make sure to install any third party library manually rather than doing `react-native link`.
Follow the detailed manual installation https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons from here.
Firstly run this command `react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons`
After unlink is successful, follow the manual installation steps.

Also it's better to use yarn (https://yarnpkg.com/en/) over npm while installing a package.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since react native 0.60 auto-linking is avaliable so that means that future libraries release won't need to run the "link" command. If you're using vector-icons you'll need to wait until the upgrade. You can use the vector icons linked to you project normally, but be careful because that will not be compatible in the next major release in react native. I also tried to upgrade to react native 0.60.3, but this is not the great idea if your using a lot of dependencies.